# How do I reference the value in an array as a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

For example, if I have the array:

```
DeviceArray = Array("Sw","Cap","Gen","Reg","Tr","Br")
```

And I want to initialize everything to a value such as 0, what would be the equivalent to writing a for loop for this such that the value within the array is treated as a variable name instead so that I can indirectly modify variable values:

```
For i = 0 to ubound(DeviceArray)
     DeviceArray(i) = 0
Next i
```

Such that after running the code, the variables:
Sw, Cap, Gen, Reg, Tr, and Br should all be set to 0.

Versus every element in DeviceArray being changed to 0 and no longer storing the strings initially placed.

So DeviceArray should remain unchanged and still store the values `("Sw","Cap","Gen","Reg","Tr","Br")`

Hope that clearly explains what I am trying to do, I am attempting to do this so I do not have to type:

```
Sw = 0
Cap = 0
Gen = 0
Reg = 0
Tr = 0
Br = 0
```

Because there is a long list of variables that need to be constantly reinitialized to different values throughout my macro.

So for example `DeviceArray(0) = Sw`, but I want the VBA macro to recognize `DeviceArray(0)` as the name of a variable `Sw` instead such that I can modify the value of the variable `Sw` without calling it directly.

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood your question; but it seems like you are proposing to create a numeric array (of ints or longs, for example). Is this what you meant?

Comment: I don't think its clear what your asking, can you describe what the resulting array would look like?

Comment: I think the question is why does this not happen: Dim arr(2) As String

Dim a As String, b As String, c As String
a = "5"
b = "asdf"
c = "lopi"

arr(0) = a
arr(1) = b
arr(2) = 3


a = "7" 'arr(0) would change to "7"

Comment: Clarified my post, hope it helps.

Comment: but this array `Array("Sw","Cap","Gen","Reg","Tr","Br")` isn't array of variable but array of string...

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are looking for a reference type rather than a value type. For this, you will need an Object in VBA.

For example, create a Class Module called `Device`. At its simplest you could just put `Public value` as the only code within the Class.

```
'Class Device
Public value
```

Now you can reference the Objects by name and pass around those references, e.g. putting them into an `Array` as in your example.

```
'Within a normal module

Public Sub test()
    Dim Sw As New Device
    Dim Cap As New Device
    Dim Gen As New Device
    Dim Reg As New Device
    Dim Tr As New Device
    Dim Br As New Device

    DeviceArray = Array(Sw, Cap, Gen, Reg, Tr, Br)
    For i = LBound(DeviceArray) To UBound(DeviceArray)
       DeviceArray(i).value = 42
    Next i

    Debug.Print Gen.value
End Sub

'Output is 42
```

Alternatively, depending on your needs, a hash map might also do the trick, in which case you would not declare variables but refer to their entries within the map.

```
Public Sub test2()
    Dim Devices As Object, DeviceArray
    Set Devices = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    DeviceArray = Array("Sw", "Cap", "Gen", "Reg", "Tr", "Br")

    For i = 0 To UBound(DeviceArray)
        Devices(DeviceArray(i)) = 0
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Gen init to ", Devices("Gen")

    Devices("Gen") = 42

    Debug.Print "Gen is now ", Devices("Gen")

    For i = 0 To UBound(DeviceArray)
        Devices(DeviceArray(i)) = 0
    Next i

    Debug.Print "Gen reset to ", Devices("Gen")
End Sub


'Gen init to    0 
'Gen is now     42 
'Gen reset to   0
```