# VBA: Change value of variables in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

How do I permanently change the value of a variable in an array? I wrote some code that illustrates my problem:

```
Option Explicit
    Dim var1 As Boolean, var2 As Boolean, var3 As Boolean

Sub Test()
    Dim arrTest As Variant
    Dim i

    arrTest = Array(var1, var2, var3)

    For Each i In arrTest
        Debug.Print i
    Next

    For i = LBound(arrTest) To UBound(arrTest)
        arrTest(i) = True
    Next

    For Each i In arrTest
        Debug.Print i
    Next

    Test2
End Sub


Sub Test2()
    Debug.Print "var1 in Sub Test2 : " & var1
    If var1 Then
        Debug.Print "Hello"
    End If
End Sub
```

*The output in the direct window is:*

```
False
False
False
True
True
True
var1 in Sub Test2 : False
```

The first six lines make sense to me because I changed the value of the variables in `Test`. However, it obviously wasn't permanent or it was confined to that one sub and so "Hello" in `Test2` didn't get printed.

How do I change this? I've read that `for each` loops are read-only, but why does the `for`-loop not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assigning "True" to every element of array does not make your variables same value.
Nothing weird your var1 is still False, because You didn't change the value of var1, but the value of your array elements. :)

Add something like this

```
var1 = arrTest(0)
var2 = arrTest(1)
var3 = arrTest(2)

Test2
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is there a reason for this, why does this make sense? And if I use the variables `var1`, `var2`, `var3` for nothing more than what I've shown in my code, is there a reason I should use an array? Simply writing `var1 = True`, `var2 = True`, `var3 = True` would be fewer lines.

Comment: Like @Patrick Honorez said below, it is a copy of you variables, not a reference.
In this case there is no need to do array or loop. It is simple case in which You can deal just like You wrote above.

Comment: And it's impossible to put them as a reference in the array?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but rather not. Instead of array try scripting.dictionary object. Maybe it will help You to improve / move further with this topic :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453272/how-do-i-reference-the-value-in-an-array-as-a-variable

Comment: I described this problem also here https://simpleexcelvba.com/change-variables-value-in-array/

Answer (score 4):

When you do `arrTest = Array(var1, var2, var3)` you **copy the values** of your variables into the arrTest. You do NOT create a reference to those variables.

Since arrTest is declared in Test() its scope is limited to Test().

If you declare arrTest at the module level, you will be able to check arrTest values from Test2. But anyway they will be completely independent from varx.

The behaviour is different if we speak about `Objects`. When we write `Set x = obj1` we DO **create a reference**, and in that case a change in obj1 will be visible in x.

Answer (score 2):

`arrTest` is a local variant variable for the `Test` sub. And this variable takes some public boolean values in it, which [are passed ByVal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/byval). If the array is declared outside the Subs itself, then it would be accessible from everywhere, exactly the way it is intended:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Dim arrTest() As Variant

Sub Test()

    Dim i
    arrTest = Array(False, False, False)

    For Each i In arrTest
        Debug.Print i
    Next

    For i = LBound(arrTest) To UBound(arrTest)
        arrTest(i) = True
    Next

    For Each i In arrTest
        Debug.Print i
    Next

    Test2

End Sub

Sub Test2()
    Debug.Print arrTest(LBound(arrTest)) 'or arrTest(0)
End Sub
```

**If you need to use variables inside array and pass them as a reference**, and not as a copy, the OOP in VBA may help. Create a class "Container", holding a property `SomeValue`, encapsulated in `valueKept`. Creating `Class` is like creating a `Module` in VBA:

[image]

```
Private valueKept As String

Public Property Get SomeValue() As String    
    SomeValue = valueKept    
End Property

Public Property Let SomeValue(ByVal myValue As String)    
    valueKept = myValue    
End Property
```

Then the `SomeValue` property of this class, could be changed ByRef, when the `Container` object is put in array:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim myArr As Variant
    Dim c1 As New Container
    Dim c2 As New Container

    c1.SomeValue = 5
    c2.SomeValue = 10

    myArr = Array(c1, c2)

    Test2 myArr
    Debug.Print c1.SomeValue '55

End Sub

Sub Test2(myArr As Variant)
    myArr(0).SomeValue = 55
End Sub
```

Comment: But using variables inside the array (as a reference and not as a copy) is not possible?

Comment: @Alex - anything is possible with VBA, just the work around could be a bit more.

Comment: I haven't done anything with `Container` objects, so I gotta familiarize myself with it, but in some way that's even better because I'm gonna learn something new. Thank you!

Comment: @Alex - `Container` is just a name of the class, it is not a real `Container`. It can be changed to anything else.